# Enable cell editing in JTable with mouseclick

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, tablecelleditor

I'm working on a Java GUI project with [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) where I inserted a JTable with a DefaultTableModel! The JTable has two columns (ID and path) and in principle two main features:

- With two JButtons "+" and "-" I can add rows to the DefaultTableModel and remove selected ones!
- With double-right click on the second column (path) a JFileChooser opens, where I can select a path, which will be set as value for the cell! For this action I implemented a CustomMouselistener and overwrote the "mousePressed" method!

**My problem:**
After implementing this stuff, I can't edit the cell with a normal mouse-click on a cell! The cells are editable, because I can edit them with "F2" - press, but it seems that I overwrote the default functionality of the mouse!

Summarized I'm using following constructs:

- Table with DefaultTableModel (2 columns)
- MouseListener for JFileChooser
- ColumnModelListener to change width of columns!

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: perhaps you could add a button "browse" for those cells that you use to invoke JFileChooser.
BTW, why do you use exclamation instead of period?

Comment: Hm, but the purpose is to insert the paths fast - otherwise I would need to select the cell first and click on the button every time. Sorry, the exclamations are habit - nothing to do with the question or you guys! :)

Comment: For editing columns use `TableCellEditor` instead of `MouseListener`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3015438/2685239
(you could put that code into your mouseClick method)